# 2018... still no way to change the region of an App Engine project or delete it?

Tags: google-app-engine

Usually i create infrastructure for my customers in GCP with their buckets on GSC, staging servers on GCE, Cloud DNS and i'm very happy with that.

But this is the third time the system does not ask me "in which region" I want to create an App Engine project and by default it places it in us-west.

Considering that I need to have all the resources in europe-west (practically all the traffic will be generated from there), I am very surprised that I cannot change the region of an application or simply delete it and recreate it.

App Engine is already a few years old and yet it seems that today (2018) the only solution we have is to recreate a new GCP project just to host our app. It doesn't make sense.

I've searched the forums, the community, and I don't see any other way.

Does anyone have a solution to change the region of an app without having to change project IDs?

Thank you very much,

Sergio

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change an [app's region](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) after you set it at the moment; however, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36878762) on it and the App Engine product team may evaluate it. So, I would recommend you to star [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36878762) for further updates.